Pod dependencies of iOS SDK not working on React Native project
I'm trying to implement an iOS SDK on an Expo React Native project.

expo: 51.0.28
react-native: 0.74.5

According to the SDK documentation, after linking the SDK on my project's iOS bundle I have to add its dependencies to the podfile archive. Like this:
pod 'SQLCipher', '~> 4.5.4' pod 'SQLCipher', '~> 4.5.4' pod 'JOSESwift', '~> 2.4.0' pod 'SwiftSignalRClient', '~> 0.9.3'  pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.7.1'

The build on Xcode works fine. However, when the app is launched on the simulator it gets frozen at the splash screen an I get the message:
dyld[11724]: Library not loaded: @rpath/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift Reason: tried: '/Volumes/T7_SAMSUNG/xcode/derivedData/myApp-ehbzoyzucsxvdiajmbdvmaooidcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CryptoSwift.framework/CryptoSwift' (no such file)

For some reason it keeps looking for CryptoSwift.framework file and that doesn't exist.
I can not figure out the origin of the error. When I pod install I can see the libraries got installed correctly. I'd say cocoapods manages all the dependencies by itself, but something is wrong. It could be the podfile configuration (generated by Expo framework):
require File.join(File.dirname(node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"), "scripts/autolinking") require File.join(File.dirname(node --print "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"`), "scripts/react_native_pods")

require 'json'podfile_properties = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join(dir, 'Podfile.properties.json'))) rescue {}

ENV['RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED'] = podfile_properties['newArchEnabled'] == 'true' ? '1' : '0'ENV['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR'] = podfile_properties['EX_DEV_CLIENT_NETWORK_INSPECTOR']

use_autolinking_method_symbol = ('use' + '_native' + '_modules!').to_symorigin_autolinking_method = self.method(use_autolinking_method_symbol)self.define_singleton_method(use_autolinking_method_symbol) do |*args|if ENV['EXPO_UNSTABLE_CORE_AUTOLINKING'] == '1'Pod::UI.puts('Using expo-modules-autolinking as core autolinking source'.green)config_command = ['node','--no-warnings','--eval','require(require.resolve('expo-modules-autolinking', { paths: [require.resolve('expo/package.json')] }))(process.argv.slice(1))','react-native-config','--json','--platform','ios']origin_autolinking_method.call(config_command)elseorigin_autolinking_method.call()end
end

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'install! 'cocoapods',:deterministic_uuids => false

prepare_react_native_project!

target 'newexpoapp' douse_expo_modules!config = use_native_modules!

use_frameworks! :linkage => podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks'].to_sym if podfile_properties['ios.useFrameworks']use_frameworks! :linkage => ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS'].to_sym if ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']

pod 'SQLCipher', '~> 4.5.4'pod 'JOSESwift', '~> 2.4.0'pod 'SwiftSignalRClient', '~> 0.9.3'pod 'CryptoSwift', '~> 1.7.1'

use_react_native!(:path => config[:reactNativePath],:hermes_enabled => podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == nil || podfile_properties['expo.jsEngine'] == 'hermes',# An absolute path to your application root.:app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/..",:privacy_file_aggregation_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.privacyManifestAggregationEnabled'] != 'false',)

post_install do |installer|react_native_post_install(installer,config[:reactNativePath],:mac_catalyst_enabled => false,:ccache_enabled => podfile_properties['apple.ccacheEnabled'] == 'true',)
    end
  end
 end
end

post_integrate do |installer| begin expo_patch_react_imports!(installer) rescue => e Pod::UI.warn e end end end 

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Thanks!
